# persisting kafka offsets between server launches

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there a way to have zookeeper preserve offsets for a given groupId? Im noticing that once a group is fully disconnected, zookeeper forgets this info, are there any settings that tell it to preserve this info?

Comment: If you use Kafka 0.9.+ offsets are not stored in ZK any longer (but stored in a Kafka topic), and you can control how long those offsets are preserved via configuration parameter.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Interesting, I'll have to take a look into it. Im noticing also that if I set the offset to be the earliest in the new consumer API to earliest I consume processed data, setting it to latest causes my tests to fail since my consumers don't consume any data which is what prompted this question. Do you have any insight here as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "you tests fails". In general, a consumer tries to resume from the latest committed offset. If there is no (valid) offset found, it either starts from the beginning or from the end of the topic.